# How to disable detailed "Compilation Error" output in web page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I would like to disable the detailed "Compilation Errors" page that is displayed when an error occurs on my ASP.NET website.  It shows:

- Title: "Compilation Error"
- Description
- Compiler Error Message
- Source Error (yellow box with the detailed line number and code error highlighted in red)
- Source File
- "Show Detailed Compiler Output"

Here's what I've already attempted:

- Within the ASP icon in IIS, set the "Enable Log Error Requests" to
  false at both site and app pool levels.
- Within the ASP icon in IIS, set the "Enable Server-side Debugging" to
  false at both site and app pool levels.
- Within the Error Pages icon in IIS, click "Edit Feature Settings...",
  select "Detailed errors" at both site and app pool levels.
- Within the web.config file, set "compilation debug=false"
- Within the web.config file, set "customErrors mode=Off"

Ideally, I'd like not to reveal the Compilation Error.  So, I'd like to know: a) how to disable these details from being displayed and show the default, and/or b) how to show my custom errors page, instead.  Thank you.

Comment: customeErrors mode="Off" means SHOW the errors... you want "On" or "RemoteOnly" which only shows them when you are on localhost.

Comment: Do you just want to do that for compilation errors, or all errors? In general, there shouldn't be compilation errors on a live site.

Comment: The customErrors mode was the problem - I misread the opposite of the documentation, but could I ask a follow-up question: If I change the mode to "On", is it possible to log in a file the error that would have been shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize it inside the web.config:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
              mode="On">
  <error statusCode="500"
         redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

More informations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Geez, silly misread of the documentation on my part.  Thanks!  Could I ask a follow-up question: If I change the mode to "On", is it possible to log in a file the error that would have been shown?

Comment: @swabygw You can redirect to a custom .aspx page and log from there.

Comment: I thought about that, but the only pertinent information I saw in the querystring was a variable "aspxerrorpath" followed by the name of the form that generated the error.  If I redirect to a custom .aspx page, is there a way to access the detailed "Compiler Error Message" and the "Source File" (though, this is probably the same as the "aspxerrorpath" and the "Line" number?

Comment: You can access the last exception occured. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You got it - but I had to add redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" to the customErrors tag, and then it worked like a charm!  Here's my code to display the error in my aspx file (sorry, not sure how to do code properly in StackOverflow) - see next comment.

Comment: <script runat="server">

Sub Page_Load()

 Dim LastError As Exception
 Dim ErrMessage As String

 LastError = Server.GetLastError

 If Not LastError Is Nothing Then
   ErrMessage = LastError.Message
 Else
   ErrMessage = "No Errors" 
 End If

 Response.Write("<b><u>ERROR MESSAGE:</u></b><br><br>" & ErrMessage)

End Sub

</script>

Comment: Errors will also show up in the Event Log of the server.